# output INT64 from js UDF

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, int64

I'm trying to use BigQuery's INT64 type to hold bit encoded information. I have to use a javascript udf function and I'd like to use all the 64 bits.

My issue is that javascript only deals with int32 so `1 << 32 == 1` and I'm not sure how to use the full 64 range that BigQuery supports in the udf.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to directly convert Big Query’s INT64 type to JavaScript UDF, neither as input nor output, as JavaScript does not support 64-bit integer type [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-type-encodings-in-javascript). You could use FLOAT64 instead, as far as the values are less than 2^53 - 1, since it follows the IEEE 754-2008 standard for double precision [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). You can also use a string containing the number value. Here is the documentation for supported external UDF data types [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-external-udf-data-types).